# "Услышать" or "послышать"?

Tags: выбор-слова, одним-словом, вид

In my vocabulary list, I have two different forms for the perfective of `слышать` listed: `услышать` and `послышать`. I know I'm not imagining this, because a practice deck I found online also had both verbs (although it was very unclear from the example sentences contained in that deck what the difference between the two is supposed to be).

**Questions:**

**1.** Are `послышать` and `услышать` exact synonyms, or are they not?

**2.** Which of the two should I memorize as the perfective form of `слышать`? Why?

**3.** Are either `послышивать` or `послушивать` actual words, and if so, are either of the two the actual imperfective form of `послышать` (instead of `слышать`)?

**Attempt:** I looked up the difference between the two, but the results were confusing to me.

Specifically, the English version of wiktionary doesn't list `послышать` as a perfective form of `слышать` -- it only lists `услышать`. `послышать` doesn't even have an entry in the English wiktionary, although it does have an entry in the Russian wiktionary, викисловарь.

But викисловарь lists `послышать` as being the perfective form of an entirely different verb: `послышивать`, for which it does not have an entry.

Yet [this Russian dictionary](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/962158) seems to list `послышать` as being an exact synonym of `услышать`. I don't quite understand what meaning the example sentences are supposed to convey, however, so I could be wrong. [This dictionary](http://www.sovslov.ru/tolk/poslyiwatyt.html), despite otherwise saying the same as the previous one, also says that the imperfective form of `послышать` is `послушивать`, instead of `послышивать`.

[This dictionary](http://xn----8sbauh0beb7ai9bh.xn--p1ai/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) gives a very similar entry for `послышать` except that it doesn't mention `услышать` again in the item containing `почуять`, instead it says:

> перен. Почуять, почувствовать.

According to [this dictionary compiler](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Dal-term-31068.htm), the difference seems to come down to whether one looks at the entry from Т.Ф. Ефремова's dictionary or the entry from Д.Н. Ушаков's dictionary.

Comment: "Послышать" is an obsolete word (as stated in one of linked dictionaries). I doubt that anybody would use it now even in written text, let alone spoken speech.

Comment: I never heard word "послышать", what it can even mean? ...Well after thinking it seems to be a valid word but related to smell rather than sounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exist verbs:

> - **слушать** - listen
> - **слышать** - hear

Their perfective forms are:

> - слушать - **послушать**
> - слышать - **услышать**

**Послушивать** (to listen periodically) is a valid word, however [Ruscorpora](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-main.html) has only 4 examples of it being used.  The examples are dating between 1857 and 1930.

**Послышать**, to my surprise, is a valid word. [Ruscorpora](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%EF%EE%F1%EB%FB%F8%E0%F2%FC&gramm1=V&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=0) has 142 examples of it being used as a perfective form of "слышать", both in modern sources and old ones. But I never heard anyone using it.

There is also a popular form **[послышаться](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F)** which has multiple meanings. It is often used in phrases "Мне послышалось" = "I think I heard it", and "Тебе послышалось" = "You are wrong about hearing it."

Comment: Thanks -- I deleted слышать/послышать from my list of words to learn.

Comment: Don't delete `слышать` - it's a valid word.